# What if an urn contain more than two categories of balls?

Tags: probability

First of all, apologies for my rusted probability.

Most -if not all- the questions about urns-and-balls assumes the urn has, for example, two colors. How would this problem be different if we have N ball categories (N>2) rather than just 2?

**Here is an example question**:

An urn has 25 balls whose weights are either 1, 2, or 3 lbs. Suppose we also know how many balls are there from each weight category. So, we perform the experiment of drawing two balls with replacement. What is the expected weight difference (for example) between the first and second draws?

If possible, I need some reading material about this please to get me started.

Answer (score 0):

Try dividing into cases:

Case 1--First draw is 1 lb. (1/3 probability)

Case 2--First draw is 2 lb. (1/3 probability)

Case 3--First draw is 3 lb. (1/3 probability)

[if you need more hints just ask]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I like the way you approached the example problem, but I need to generalize this to N categories (so N is a parameter in this case). Clearly, dividing into cases will result in a big tree for large N.